# Blank screen when running a Java FX 2.0 application on linux

Tags: linux, javafx

So, I just started toying with Java FX on Linux since the developer preview finally came out. I'm following the first example on the site ([Getting Started with JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm)) and everything seems to be running OK. However, all I get is a blank window when running the example.

I've checked to make sure I'm using the JRE included on the JDK7u3 for linux.

The weird thing is I don't get any exceptions or problems when running the example, I just get the blank window which does nothing. I can even set some properties for the Stage, like setting the title or the size, and those changes are reflected; but nothing on the Scene shows, not even the background color.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I may be doing wrong?

UPDATE:
Thanks for your reply; here's the code and the screenshot, Sergey. I removed most of the example and left only the stage creation:

```
    public class UITest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage mainStage) {
        try {
            Group root = new Group();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300, Color.RED);
            mainStage.setScene(scene);
            mainStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This shows [THIS](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_B_sex_Yu7c/T2eHeud8b0I/AAAAAAAAACs/Q0hfi7B39XA/s402/javafx_stage.png) window.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and running the example on Eclipse.

The output with the -Dprism.verbose=true argument is:

```
Prism pipeline init order: es2 j2d 
Using t2k for text rasterization
Using dirty region optimizations
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ...
    succeeded.
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
**** GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object detected ****
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
RESIZE: 6378396429620 w: 432 h: 1
Created GL2ES2: com.sun.prism.opengl.impl.gl2.GL2Impl@132e1b6
  GL_VENDOR:     NVIDIA Corporation
  GL_RENDERER:   Quadro FX 350M/PCI/SSE2
  GL_VERSION:    2.1.2 NVIDIA 280.13
  GL_EXTENSIONS: 
    GL_ARB_color_buffer_float
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer
    GL_ARB_depth_clamp
    GL_ARB_depth_texture
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location
    GL_ARB_fragment_program
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex
    GL_ARB_imaging
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range
    GL_ARB_multisample
    GL_ARB_multitexture
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_point_parameters
    GL_ARB_point_sprite
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex
    GL_ARB_robustness
    GL_ARB_sampler_objects
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects
    GL_ARB_shader_objects
    GL_ARB_shading_language_100
    GL_ARB_shading_language_include
    GL_ARB_shadow
    GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp
    GL_ARB_texture_compression
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3
    GL_ARB_texture_float
    GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle
    GL_ARB_texture_rg
    GL_ARB_texture_swizzle
    GL_ARB_timer_query
    GL_ARB_transpose_matrix
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_vertex_program
    GL_ARB_vertex_shader
    GL_ARB_window_pos
    GL_ATI_draw_buffers
    GL_ATI_texture_float
    GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once
    GL_S3_s3tc
    GL_EXT_texture_env_add
    GL_EXT_abgr
    GL_EXT_bgra
    GL_EXT_blend_color
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax
    GL_EXT_blend_subtract
    GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array
    GL_EXT_Cg_shader
    GL_EXT_depth_bounds_test
    GL_EXT_direct_state_access
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements
    GL_EXT_fog_coord
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
    GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil
    GL_EXT_packed_pixels
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object
    GL_EXT_point_parameters
    GL_EXT_provoking_vertex
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal
    GL_EXT_secondary_color
    GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color
    GL_EXT_shadow_funcs
    GL_EXT_stencil_two_side
    GL_EXT_stencil_wrap
    GL_EXT_texture3D
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
    GL_EXT_texture_cube_map
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine
    GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
    GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
    GL_EXT_texture_lod
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp
    GL_EXT_texture_object
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle
    GL_EXT_timer_query
    GL_EXT_vertex_array
    GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra
    GL_EXT_x11_sync_object
    GL_EXT_import_sync_object
    GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat
    GL_KTX_buffer_region
    GL_NV_alpha_test
    GL_NV_blend_minmax
    GL_NV_blend_square
    GL_NV_complex_primitives
    GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color
    GL_NV_depth_clamp
    GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments
    GL_NV_fence
    GL_NV_float_buffer
    GL_NV_fog_distance
    GL_NV_fragdepth
    GL_NV_fragment_program
    GL_NV_fragment_program_option
    GL_NV_fragment_program2
    GL_NV_framebuffer_multisample_coverage
    GL_NV_half_float
    GL_NV_light_max_exponent
    GL_NV_multisample_filter_hint
    GL_NV_occlusion_query
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil
    GL_NV_pixel_data_range
    GL_NV_point_sprite
    GL_NV_primitive_restart
    GL_NV_register_combiners
    GL_NV_register_combiners2
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection
    GL_NV_texture_barrier
    GL_NV_texture_compression_vtc
    GL_NV_texture_env_combine4
    GL_NV_texture_expand_normal
    GL_NV_texture_lod_clamp
    GL_NV_texture_rectangle
    GL_NV_texture_shader
    GL_NV_texture_shader2
    GL_NV_texture_shader3
    GL_NV_vertex_array_range
    GL_NV_vertex_array_range2
    GL_NV_vertex_program
    GL_NV_vertex_program1_1
    GL_NV_vertex_program2
    GL_NV_vertex_program2_option
    GL_NV_vertex_program3
    GL_NVX_conditional_render
    GL_OES_depth24
    GL_OES_depth32
    GL_OES_depth_texture
    GL_OES_element_index_uint
    GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
    GL_OES_get_program_binary
    GL_OES_mapbuffer
    GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
    GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
    GL_OES_standard_derivatives
    GL_OES_texture_3D
    GL_OES_texture_float
    GL_OES_texture_float_linear
    GL_OES_texture_half_float
    GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
    GL_OES_texture_npot
    GL_OES_vertex_array_object
    GL_OES_vertex_half_float
    GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod
    GL_SGIX_depth_texture
    GL_SGIX_shadow
    GL_SUN_slice_accum
RESIZE: 6378695960023 w: 1 h: 1
RESIZE: 6378733837813 w: 400 h: 300
```

Comment: it's a developer's preview so not all Linux versions and hardware are supported. What is your OS version? Also, can you try to run application with flag `-Dprism.verbose=true` and provide output?

Comment: anyone who has had this happen?

Comment: can't reproduce it on my Linux. Do you use latest version of JavaFX?

Comment: Yes, I just downloaded the developer preview a couple days ago, JavaFX 2.1 build b17.

Comment: Added output of -DPrism.verbose=true argument

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else was having the same problem, it turned out to be an issue of the JVM, not the JafaFX JDK. The problem occurs in Linux when using window manager with effects, like when using Compiz. It seems this used to happen before JRE1.6, and was supposed to have been solved after update 1.6u3, but apparently it happens again with JRE1.7.

The fix was setting another window manager name with suckless-tools' wmname utility. For me it worked by setting it to LG3D.

Hope this helps someone.
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Prism output looks correct, with this hardware and pipeline fx should work on your linux. Can you, please, run next code (which adds a simple object to scene and sets title)?

```
public class UITest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage mainStage) {
        Group root = new Group(new Button("hello"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300, Color.RED);
        mainStage.setScene(scene);
        mainStage.setTitle("fx test");
        mainStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(); }
}
```

Comment: The stage's title does change, but there are still no components inside the window :S Here's the [WINDOW](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-NslLieWa2wA/T20mWJ_B6lI/AAAAAAAAADM/idjqepIOyNk/s870/javafx_stage_with_button.png).

Comment: As an additional note, if I try to run one of the examples included on the javafx-samples-2.1.0-beta, I get a window with the following message: **JavaFX 2.1.0 is required to view this content but JavaFX. Get the JavaFX runtime from java.com/javafx and run the installer. Then restart the application.**

I thought the runtime was included on the JDK, though, so I assume this are applets and are trying to run on a browser window.